# Grouping results using MIN operator

Tags: mysql

first sorry for the silly question but I'm not an expert using SQL. I've done some search about this, but none of the answers were working for me.

I have a table with this structure:

| sensor_id | temp_value | temp_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TEMP_1 | 19 | 00:00:07 |
| TEMP_1 | 13 | 01:00:00 |
| TEMP_1 | 11 | 03:10:10 |
| TEMP_1 | 15 | 07:33:49 |
| TEMP_2 | 25 | 00:00:07 |
| TEMP_2 | 20 | 01:00:00 |
| TEMP_2 | 22 | 03:10:10 |
| TEMP_2 | 28 | 07:33:49 |

I would like to get the minimum value for each sensor_id but with the corresponding time.
Here is the query I do:

```
SELECT MIN(temp_value) as value,sensor_id,temp_time FROM nd_sensor_value
WHERE sensor_id = "TEMP_1" OR sensor_id = "TEMP_2" GROUP BY sensor_id
```

*(I've added the sensor_id in WHERE because I have lot of other sensors in the table but I want just these 2)*

With this query I get this result:

| sensor_id | temp_value | temp_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TEMP_1 | 11 | 00:00:07 |
| TEMP_2 | 20 | 00:00:07 |

The values are okay, but the time isn't. It takes the min value but with the time of the first record.
This is the result I expect:

| sensor_id | temp_value | temp_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TEMP_1 | 11 | 03:10:10 |
| TEMP_2 | 20 | 01:00:00 |

I'm using MySQL with PHP, it is for a side project.
I know that there is lots of way to do it, but my table contains a huge amount of records and I'm looking for the more optimal query.

Is Anyone able to help me with this ?

Many thanks !

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71a75cc8cbfa8a33e75ed819476f1037

Comment: It is MySQL 5.6. Many thanks, your query is totally answering to my problem !

Comment: And if I wanted only the results of a specific date ? (field temp_date)

Comment: Manipulate the select statement https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=03c1da3aeb6fa2056dd8034487e65c49